# What is the default UV behavior?

Tags: texturing, uv

I selected part of my mesh (the head of a character) and did a "Smart UV Project". For the rest of the mesh, I didn't do any UV operations.
In the shader, I added a Texture Image and set an image.
One copy of the image is now plastered across the head of the character, which is what I intended.
But the image is also repeated all over the character, anywhere else where the material is applied.

From this I infer that for any face of the character where I didn't specify any UV mapping manually, one UV island is created.
Is this correct?

Comment: For the rest, it's not even an "island" per se, it's more of a "dot" (all UV data in one single point) - just the same as the whole mesh UV is before you unwrap it.

Comment: the other faces will be unwrapped as they were already unwrapped, they won't be unwrapped with the Smart UV Project if you didn't use select them

Comment: If you just added one material to your object, that will be the default material for the whole object so any image will appear on the whole object whether it's all been UV unwrapped or not. You need to first add a default material, then add another one with your image on it. Then select the head in Edit mode, select the material with the image, and click 'Apply' below the material slots.